# Regex matching parent pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I have this string:

```
string result = "User operation: <#user#>  Computer: <#computername#> Description: <#TemplateDescription(<#user#>)#>"
```

I need Regex pattern for finding this tags list (only parent tag!):

```
<#user#>
<#computername#>
<#TemplateDescription(<#user#>)#>
```

I am currently using the following regular expression:

```
List<string>    loTags  =   Regex.Matches(result, "<#(.*?)#>")
                                 .Cast<Match>()
                                 .Select(loTag => string.Format("<#{0}#>",
                                                                loTag.Groups[1].Value))
                                 .ToList();
```

and the result is this:

```
<#user#>
<#computername#>
<#TemplateDescription(<#user#>
```

How do I modify my regular expression?

Comment: is your result missing a closing `#>` at the end?

Comment: sorry I forgot a #> at the end of the string

Comment: so is this `<#TemplateDescription(<#user#>)` your expected output?

Comment: I expected:
<#user#>
<#computername#>
<#TemplateDescription(<#user#>)#>

Comment: @ChuckM90 Is that in one line or three separate values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go,

```
@"<#((?:<#.*?#>|(?!<#|#>).)*)#>"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/oH6lM5/1)

`<#.*?#>` Matches all the `<# #>` blocks. If any character appears other than this , then the pattern next to the `|` OR operator is used . In our case, it's `(?!<#|#>).`, which matches any character but not of `<#` or `#>`

Answer (score 0):

Change your regex to `"<#(.*?)#>([)](#>))?"` to match and retrieve an optional closing parenthesis along with the desired pattern at the end.

[Demo](http://rextester.com/XVKBU62062)

Comment: You're welcome. Make sure that you understand the concepts from your accepted solution properly :)